# No current pull even with voltage present

Tags: led, voltage-regulator

Following is my schematic[image]

Checked voltage. I am getting 3.6V
Chekced current, 0Ampere. ALso LED does not glow.

Tried changing the regulator to AMS1117-3.3. But still no luck. Same exact conditions.

What may be the issue?

Comment: You've wired the LED backwards?

Comment: How? It is wired correctly! I tried wiring it other way round. It still doesnt light. But it lights when I switch off the supply, because the capacitor discharges through it

Comment: what is the forward voltage drop of the led?

Comment: MIN 1.6V to 2.2V MAX

Comment: and what is the maximum forward current?

Comment: @SanjeevKumar 20mA Absolute Maximum

Comment: Waaaaaaaait! **There's different variants of the LM1117**, with different fixed voltages and one with adjustable output. **Which one are you using?**

Comment: fixed output LM1117. it is LM1117-3.3. I tried it with the AMS1117-3.3 too. But I am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

As Listed above 
Vout from regulator=3.6V

Forward voltage drop (Vf) range is 1.6V to 2.2V and

Absolute Maximum rating of current(If) is 20mA

The resistor (R)used in series is 62ohm.

**Condition:1**

When Vf=1.6V Then the current flowing through led will be (3.6-1.6)/62=**32 mA**

**Condition:2**

When Vf=2.2V Then the current flowing through led will be (3.6-2.2)/62=**22.5 mA**

So in both the condition the absolute maximum rating of current is crossed.

Looks like LED has blown up.I will suggest to use some lower value of resistor around 110ohm and test the setup with new led.

Thanks.

Comment: I tested the LED. The LED is not blown. It glows when tested with other source.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried wiring it other way round. It still doesnt light. But it lights when I switch off the supply, because the capacitor discharges through it

That means the voltage supplied by the LM1117 is sufficient, as it's identical to the voltage across the capacitor.

The only other thing that could go wrong here is that the LM1117 simply can't offer enough current – but even if the LED had a 0 V forward voltage, the 62 Ω resistor would limit the current to about 60 mA – and that's, by far, below what the LM1117 can supply.

So, there's only two options:

1. You forgot to mention there's a diode in here, something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqdUNL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which would explain why it works in reverse, not in normal configuration, or

2. your 12V source in fact isn't able to supply the current to light the LED, so while it's able to slowly charge the capacitor while the LED is not conducting (due to being connected in reverse), it's not able to supply enough current to the LED.

Answer (score 0):

Try some diagnostics:
1) What is the INPUT current? LM1117 typically draws 5mA.
2) Can regulator supply current to a resistive load? Put 180ohms across output and see what happens.

Regulators like this have a MINIMUM current load specified; no parameter is guaranteed until this current is taken. Consequently, measuring the supposedly correct output voltage at zero load means nothing.

Be sure to check for oscillation; the input capacitor - which should be tantalum, or have a small ceramic capacitor in parallel - should be close to the regulator.